# How to count the number of occurence of images in an array REGEX

Tags: php, arrays, regex

I have an array something like this

```
ARRAY[0][DATAROOT.PROPIEDADES.FOTO1][0]
ARRAY[0][DATAROOT.PROPIEDADES.FOTO2][0]
ARRAY[0][DATAROOT.PROPIEDADES.FOTO3][0]
ARRAY[0][DATAROOT.PROPIEDADES.FOTO4][0]
```

I have to write a script to count the number of the photos in the array:

```
$x = "DATAROOT.PROPIEDADES.FOTO";

$ct = 8; // This is the number of image I am passing fixed variable
```

I want to get that using the array I need to find out a way that will count the array

that has column name `DATAROOT.PROPIEDADES.FOTO` with `1`, `2`,`3` etc in the end.

This I am not able to do

```
for($tt=1;$tt<=$ct;$tt++)
{   
    $k=$x.$tt;     
    $result[]=$this->ARRAY[0][$k][0];
}
```

Can any one help me in this .

Thanks in Advance

Comment: count the array column? you already got it inside `$ct`

Comment: @ghost  yes but I should get it dynamically . Because I will not be knowing how many images are there in the arrays . Or if you suggest some other way to do this . That would be great

Comment: are there other indices in that array that isn't named `DATAROOT.PROPIEDADES.FOTO`?

Comment: @Ghost yes something like `DATAROOT.PROPIEDADES.DESCRIPCION`, `DATAROOT.PROPIEDADES.TITULO` etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative, you could just get those elements inside the parent array whose keys has that substring:

```
$x = 'DATAROOT.PROPIEDADES.FOTO';
foreach($this->ARRAY[0] as $k => $value) {
    if(strpos($k, $x) !== false) {
        $result[] = $value[0];
    }
}
```

Or:

```
foreach($this->ARRAY[0] as $k => $value) {
    if(preg_match('~DATAROOT\.PROPIEDADES\.FOTO\d+~', $k)) {
        $result[] = $value[0]
    }
}
```